# Linq - The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'join'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an existing linq query and i need to make some changes to it, I tried joining a inmemory object to the query but i am seeing the compile error, i am using EF core

> The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect.
> Type inference failed in the call to 'join

My code looks like below.

This is a simplified version of actual issue, here i am trying to join empEligible to the existing Linq query and it is not allowwing to join

```
EmployeeMaster empM = new EmployeeMaster();
int Id = 5663;
EmployeeEligibility empEligible = _empDBContext.EmpEligibilities.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGetEmployeeDetails({EmpId})").FirstOrDefault();

empM = (from a in _empDBContext.Departments.AsNoTracking()
join b in _empDBContext.Crieterias on a.RollId equals b.RollId
join c in _empDBContext.Merits.AsNoTracking() on b.MeritId equals c.MeritId
join d in _empDBContext.Orders.AsNoTracking() on c.HistoryId equals d.HistoryId
join e in _empDBContext.Transactions.AsNoTracking() on a.RollId equals e.RollId
join f in empEligible on empEligible.Id equals Id
select new EmployeeMaster 
{
});
)
```

tried this way also , but is giving an error

> An expression of type 'EmployeeEligibility' is not allowed in a
> subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type
> ÍQueryable<<anonymous type: <anonymous type: >' Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'

```
 EmployeeMaster empM = new EmployeeMaster();
    int Id = 5663;
    EmployeeEligibility empEligible = _empDBContext.EmpEligibilities
             .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGetEmployeeDetails({EmpId})")
             .FirstOrDefault();

empM = (from a in _empDBContext.Departments.AsNoTracking()
join b in _empDBContext.Crieterias on a.RollId equals b.RollId
join c in _empDBContext.Merits.AsNoTracking() on b.MeritId equals c.MeritId
join d in _empDBContext.Orders.AsNoTracking() on c.HistoryId equals d.HistoryId
join e in _empDBContext.Transactions.AsNoTracking() on a.RollId equals e.RollId
from v in empEligible where empEligible.Id == Id
select new EmployeeMaster 
{
});
)
```

Comment: if there is no relation between `empEligible` and others entities, use `from f in empEligible where f.Id = Id`

Comment: @MongZhu typo error, corrected

Comment: @Sajid tried it but it is also giving error, i have updated my post.

Comment: @user3198688 why are you using those JOINs in the first place? It's EF Core's job to generate JOINs from entity relations. If you really need to use 5 JOINs in a LINQ query, you should probably consider writing a VIEW or UDF instead and map the results to it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is an existing linq query, i need to make change it by adding a new join to a UDF.

Comment: @user3198688 it's still a bad query. If there are so many joins, either the DbContext is missing relations or the entire query should be replaced by SQL. ORMs are meant to Map Objects to Relational tables, not replace SQL. Reporting queries are one particular case where ORMs are a *bad* fit

Comment: Even if you don't want to replace the LINQ query, it's easier to write the SQL query, test it and only then try to rewrite it as a LINQ query.

Comment: Once you format the code though, the problem is obvious. `empEligible ` is *not* a query, it's a single object. It can't be used in an `in` clause. You're trying to rewrite a complex SQL query using a correlated subquery as LINQ. That's not what LINQ and EF Core are meant for.

Comment: You sample code still has `join f in empEligible on empEligible.Id equals Id` which won't compile. Please correct your code to at least be close to compiling. Types are your friend - generally if C# compiler can't infer types for `join`, that means you have a type mismatch across the `equals`.